# Merge DataFrames Together in a List by Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of DataFrames and I'm trying to merge two of them together in place within the list by using integer indexes stored in variables. Currently I'm using `.join()`. This works for joining the DataFrames together, but it is making a copy of one of the dataframes, rather than actually merging the two together.

```py
df_list[index1] = df_list[index1].join(df_list[index2])

df_list[index1] 
4  12  
 C  C  
 G  N  
 K  M  
 C  C  
 G  N  
 Y  F  
 G  N  
 G  Y  

df_list[index2] 
8
S
A
M
S
A
H
A
A
```

My output below showing just the column labels in each DataFrame. Notice how 8 is joined to (4 12) but it is still appearing in it's own DataFrame:

```
(10)(9)(14)(7)(13)(6)(2)( 4 12  8)(1)(3)(8)(11)(5)
```

My desired output:

```
(10)(9)(14)(7)(13)(6)(2)( 4 12  8)(1)(3)(11)(5)
```

Comment: can you show what `df_list[index1]` and `df_list[index2]` looks like?

Comment: use `pop`...? ie `df_list[index1] = df_list[index1].join(df_list.pop(index2))`

Answer (score 1):

You don't copy the df element, you actively overwrite the element of the list in Index1 with the new, joined data frame. Just delete the Index2 element from the list after merging:

```
del df_list[index2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`list.pop`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). This both removes **and** returns the element at the given index.

```
df_list[index1] = df_list[index1].join(df_list.pop(index2))
```